# How to have collapsable headings in markdown?

Tags: javascript, markdown, slate

I am using slate, https://github.com/lord/slate, for API documentation. Using slate, a markdown file is converted to HTML. I need to have collapsable sections in my final HTML page. I appreciate if you let me know about the best approach?

Comment: Collapsing regions require either scripting or a `:checked` style with hidden `<input type="checkbox" />` elements - both of which are dependent on the context the Markdown-generated HTML is being rendered into. This is not something built-in to Markdown at all.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service. [Do some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/497418) and when you've got a real question, feel free to ask it here. Until then, if you have a work order, go hire a developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, markdown or slate don't support this directly. One option could be to mix the [`<summary>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_summary.asp) and [`<details>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_details.asp) html tags in with your markdown, but then you'd have to style it yourself to match slate's style.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your help. I appreciate it.